# Solr results grouped by field (but facet based grouping)

Tags: solr, autocomplete, lucene, facet, autosuggest

I use Apache Lucene Solr for indexing and searching data. Here, i'm trying to build the autocomplete operation:

I have documents, for example persons. Let's say that a person is described by some fields in document, id, name, job, nationality. (Nick Fury, Doctor, English / John Dock, Teacher, Dominican / Jim Tyson, Dock Worker, Polish). When i write "do" we want the suggestions to be:

--- Job (label)

Doctor

Dock Worker

---Nationality (label)

Dominican

---Name (label)

John Dock

So, we want something like Suggester, i tried it, but with results grouped according to the field matched, always with a certain order: first the matched jobs, then nationalities if exist ...., and if possible, inside categories we can sort by count or relevance.

Then, i tried with 3 facets. But i can't find how to group facets so as to have the jobs, nationalities .... grouped all together.

Is there any way to do this? In solr irc some people answered that i have to use 2 queries. How can i do this?

It is something like this http://www.cominvent.com/2012/01/25/super-flexible-autocomplete-with-solr/ , but there, only one field is searched and then it is grouped by a category. In my example, the case of that would be, typing "co" returning:

--- Category

Countries

Continents

--- Countries & Cities

Colombia

Costa Rica
...

Answer (score 0):

You could create different suggesters for each field in the "suggest" component:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
   <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">job</str>
      <str name="field">job</str>
      ...
   </lst>
<lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">nationality</str>
      <str name="field">nationality</str>
      ...
   </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

(you can add more suggesters...)

Then a single "/suggest" request handler:

```
<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
  <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">all</str>
      <str name="wt">json</str>
      <str name="indent">false</str>
    <str name="suggest">true</str>
    <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>suggest</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Then on the client side:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/suggest?suggest.q=co&suggest.dictionary=job&suggest.dictionary=nationality
```